# Overfull hbox when using flushright

Tags: paragraphs

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt, B5]{letter}
\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage[italian,french,spanish,icelandic,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % Programming tools

\title{First document}
\author{Randy}
\date{September 2022}

\signature{Randy}

\address{51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor \\
  Boston, MA 02110 \\
  USA}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Local Council}

  \opening{Mayor}

  A paragraph 

  \begin{flushright}
    \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
    \signature{Randy}
  \end{flushright}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

is giving

```
Overfull \hbox (20.11418pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 154--154
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: please always provide an example that produces the warning you are asking about. All we know is some code you have not shown is making some text wider than a page width you have not shown, it is not possible to help.

Comment: I just put the part where `lualatex` complained.  Was unaware the rest of the code mattered.

Comment: I guess you want to place the `\closing` part and the signature at the right margin. Using `flushright` is not the answer. Besides, it would be typographically very disputable; maybe the signature, but definitely not the `\closing`.

Comment: To be on the right side, as it is printing in the middle.

Comment: What could I use instead of `\flushright` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overfull box message is independent on `flushright`, as you can check by removing it.

You can look in the class file the definition of `\closing`:

```
% letter.cls, line 234:
\newcommand\closing[1]{\par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
  \stopbreaks
  \noindent
  \ifx\@empty\fromaddress\else
  \hspace*{\longindentation}\fi
  \parbox{\indentedwidth}{\raggedright
       \ignorespaces #1\\[6\medskipamount]%
       \ifx\@empty\fromsig
           \fromname
       \else \fromsig \fi\strut}%
   \par}
```

If you look for the value of `\longindentation` and `\indentedwidth`, you see 195pt for both. Their sum is 390pt, which is the standard textwidth for the `letter` class, but you specify a different textwidth of 13cm, in points 369.88582pt. The difference is exactly what you get in the warning

```
Overfull \hbox (20.11418pt too wide)
```

If you really want to push the closing and the signature flush to the right margin, you need to modify the definition of `\closing`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{letter}
\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\closing}[1]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
  \stopbreaks
  \noindent
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
    #1\\[6\medskipamount]
    \ifx\@empty\fromsig
      \fromname
    \else
      \fromsig
   \fi
  \end{tabular}\par
}
\makeatother

\date{September 2022}

\signature{Randy}

\address{51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor \\
  Boston, MA 02110 \\
  USA}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Local Council}

\opening{Mayor}

A paragraph

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't do it. If you want to stick with the standard way, so the closing and signature start in the middle of the page, add instead in the preamble

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\longindentation}{0.5\textwidth}%
  \setlength{\indentedwidth}{0.5\textwidth}%
}
```

or you may choose different proportions.

Here's the example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{letter}
\usepackage[b5paper,body={13cm,18cm}]{geometry}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\longindentation}{0.5\textwidth}%
  \setlength{\indentedwidth}{0.5\textwidth}%
}

\date{September 2022}

\signature{Randy}

\address{51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor \\
  Boston, MA 02110 \\
  USA}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Local Council}

\opening{Mayor}

A paragraph

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]